# QIntValidator for PyQt6 Subclass Overide for fixup() not Functioning

Tags: qlineedit, pyqt6, qvalidator

I'm trying to override fixup in QIntValidator for PyQt6.
I have verified that the subclass is being applied by looking at the appropriate object in a watch table.
However, behaviors that I put into fixup() do not execute.
It seems as though the core QIntValidator fixup() is working because if I try to type a letter into the applicable field, no text can be entered.
Numbers can be entered, however, just as you'd expect from a QIntValidator fixup() call.
Right now, I'm just putting a simple print command in, but I have tried several other behaviors and none of them have worked.

I have already worked around this by modifying the slot connected to the text input signal, but I'd like to know the "correct" way to do this using the validator since that can be inherited by any instantiations.

Here is my watch table showing that the correct parent classes for my two validation schemes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i888L.png)

Here is the StepsInput subclass:

```
from IntValidator import IntValidator
from LabeledInputInput import LabeledInputInput


class StepsInput(LabeledInputInput):
    
    def set_validator(self)-> None:
        validator = IntValidator(1, 255)
        self.setValidator(validator)
        return
```

Here is the IntValidator subclass

```
from PyQt6.QtGui import QIntValidator


class IntValidator(QIntValidator):
    
    def fixup(self, input):
        input = "123"
        return input
```

Here is the LabeledInputInput parent class:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QLineEdit
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QRegularExpression
from PyQt6.QtGui import QRegularExpressionValidator
from PasteToMenu import PasteToMenu


class LabeledInputInput(QLineEdit):
    
    context_menu: PasteToMenu
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.context_menu = PasteToMenu()
        self.__set_appearance()
        self.set_validator()
        return
    
    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        self.context_menu.exec(event.globalPos())
        return
    
    def __set_appearance(self)-> None:
        self.setFixedSize(50, 20)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.setStyleSheet(self.__generate_style_sheet())
        return
    
    def __generate_style_sheet(self)-> str:
        return '''        
            LabeledInputInput {
                background-color: #EEEEEE;
                border: 2px solid #FFD369;
                color: #393E46;
                font-size: 10pt;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        ''' 
    
    def set_validator(self)-> None:
        pattern = '[0-9]+'
        regex = QRegularExpression(pattern)
        validator = QRegularExpressionValidator(regex)
        self.setValidator(validator)
        return
```

Comment: If you read the [QValidator docs](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalidator.html#details), it says: "QLineEdit, for example, will call fixup() if the user presses Enter (or Return) and the content is not currently valid.". Also, your assumption that "the core QIntValidator fixup() is working" is wrong, because the fact that you're not able to type an unacceptable character is controlled by `validate()`, not `fixup()`. As the name suggests, "fix up" will eventually *fix* the input, not decide if it's acceptable it or not.

Comment: 1) pressing enter or return does not result in the modified fixup being called
2) I assumed that fixup() was called when validate() passed the Invalid constant. Surely the validator does not have the exact same fixup code copy and pasted in it as the fixup() method...
3) This response hasn't really helped at all and you haven't asked any clarifying questions so what was the point?

Comment: I don't know what you tried, but using your own code, your `fixup()` *is* called whenever the *input text* (not while typing, but after the text is set) is invalid and after pressing enter: for instance, if the contents of the line edit are cleared and you press enter, `123` will appear, which is exactly the documented and expected behavior. If you want to call `fixup()` during input evaluation, you must do that explicitly in `validate()`, possibly after calling the base implementation and checking if the resulting state is `Invalid`.

Comment: @musicanmante Okay, I figured this out and I see what you were saying now. The validator stops the input from being processed by the application. So not no signals are emitted on invalid input and the input is never saved to the widget. Since the input is totally blocked, there is nothing to fixup. If I want to modify the validation I actually need to modify QIntValidator's validate method. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You're very welcome! Yes, if you want to fix the input *while it's **typed***, you have to override `validate()`, since that's the only function that gets called when the user tries to change the content of the line edit. `fixup()` is not called while typing, but only whenever the *already typed* text is invalid and the widget calls it (as said, when Enter/Return is pressed, or when `interpretText()` is called, which only happens for QAbstractSpinBox subclasses). Also, don't confuse function calls, events and signals: there's no signal related to invalid input, unless you implement it.

Comment: All Qt text-input controls use an internal control that "decides" whether a key input is accepted or not. Whenever a widget supports a QValidator [sub]class, it calls it with the possible resulting input, and decides if the input is acceptable (`Intermediate`/ `Acceptable`) or not (`Invalid`): if it's *not* `Invalid`, the text is accepted and *may* alter the actual visible text value, but if it *is* `Invalid`, the input is rejected and the control eventually decides what to do with the given text and cursor position. This clearly means that if the input is invalid, there's nothing to "fix up".